# Is there a way to restrict push access to users on a local git repo?

Tags: git, authorization, gerrit

In the currently workflow, we have a centeralized git repo. This git repo is supposed to be "blessed", where code is heavily QA'd and Verfied. This means any developer is not allowed to push to this blessed repo, the only entity that is allowed to push to this blessed repo is Gerrit. I have treated Gerrit as a gatekeeper, but from a secuirty aspect the devleoper could bypass this and push directly to the blessed repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never trust those evil developers! They are pushing code everywhere. ;-)

The [git-scm page](http://git-scm.com/) very extensively explains how to [enforce access using ACLs](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy) via git hooks.

Comment: Thanks. It would be an amazing day when you can trust the evil developers. I wouldn't exactly call them evil either, just lazy.